# how can I plot Interactive plot for a dask data frame using plotly

Tags: python, plot, plotly, dask, dask-dataframe

I have a Dask data frame that have 30  partitions, (each partition) have 100 million raws of data. total number of raws in the whole dask dataframe is 400 million raws. I would like to plot all of the Daskframe in one plot using plotly. How would I go about achieving this? The end result is an over all plot of the data and if I want to explor a specific region of the data I can zoom in and pan. My data size is about 3.5 GB, and they wont fot in memory.

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Comment: Welcome to stack overflow! Please see the guide to [ask]. Keep in mind that we're volunteers - read your question from our perspective and see if it makes sense and can reasonably be answered with the informaiton you provide. Check out the guide to creating a [mre] too. It would be really helpful if you could explain more about the structure of your data, and how you're thinking about plotting it. are the values strings? numeric? polygons? what do you mean when you say explore a specific region of the data? do you want to examine groups of rows? or subset the data spatially somehow?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71642795/browser-is-crashing-when-using-dropdown-component-with-large-data-in-plotly-dash/71692056#71692056

Answer (score 1):

`3.5GB` is a fairly small size, so should fit in memory. If it doesn't, there are a few strategies:

1. reduce data by selecting only columns of interest, load into memory and plot data with standard libraries:

```py
from dask.dataframe import read_parquet

df = read_parquet(path_to_file, columns=specific_cols).compute()
```

2. datashader - https://plotly.com/python/datashader/